# Slow performance in SQL Server 2008

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2008-r2

The project I've been working is consist of a service project using WebApi, and few client projects in different platform (Desktop and Mobile). The service project serves all the request by validating the user credentials against my client's business requirement and communicates with the database using Entity Framework 5.

Everything works fine in my development PC (with **Windows 8** and **SQL Server 2012 Express**). But when I deploy the service application to the production server (with **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise** and **SQL Server 2008 Standard**), unfortunately each and every request takes too much time.

For example, the most expensive service method that analyzes almost all the transactions in one year, takes maximum 500 ms in my development PC, but in the server it takes as much as 35-40 seconds.

For some reason, I had `MultipleActiveResultSets` enables, disabling that didn't help. apart from that, I tried re-installing SQL Server, IIS and the whole Windows, but couldn't do any better.

Any Advice? Please.

Comment: I would try running the queries directly against the database first to see if SQL Server is the problem.  Forget about your app for the timebeing until you've run the queries against the local database and the production database

Comment: Can you post the sql that is causing the 500ms request on your development PC. (Profile the DB to get the SQL that EF generates)

Comment: What's taking longer? The queries, or the request? PS you really need to get a staging server set up.

Comment: I tested using the SQL Server Profiler and the queries are taking longer than usual, but if i run these queries in the SMSS, they work just fine. everything was just fine just before i migrated the whole project from WCF to WebApi.

@Martin I do check each service method using my browser, even a simple `_db.Employees.OfType<T>().Where(x=> x.IsActive)` takes 15-20 sec in the production server (while it may return 20 rows out of 200 from the table).

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Are both the .NET code and SQL on the same physical hardware or over the wire?

Comment: Could it be a network latency issue? It takes more time to send data across a network. A Query generated by EF could be sending way more data across the network than you want, is the query sending only the data you actually need? ANd is there some reason why you used a database other than the one you were devloping for? SQL server 2012 has different performance specs than 2008. Never develop on any tools or datbases other than the ones that will be used on prod.

Comment: Yes, both application and sql server are on same hardware.

@HLGEM I had no choice coz I switched to VS2012 during the development, i will remember this advice anyway in the future. now i don't have any way other than to ask the client to buy SQL Server 2012 :P

Comment: if the SQL that is generated by EF (the one you see in profiler) in Production is the same as is in development, AND the size of the database (Row count, data etc.) is the same in both environments, you have a problem with the SQL server installation. As @HLGEM said, it could be the amount of time it takes transfer the data

Comment: Basically, there is not nearly enough information for us to provide a decent analysis for you.  Could it be that the indexes aren't in place? could it be the Disk speed of the database server. Could it be that there is just a lot more data on production than Dev?

Comment: If as you say the queries appear to run fine in SSMS, have you looked at perfmon counters at all?

Comment: @Martin I really don't think any more information can help you understand the situation coz a simple 'select * from <some_table>' performs much slower in the production server (even if there is no data in the table at all), This is mysterious! I think there is a problem in sql server installation (though i didn't make any customization in the installation process), besides all other application are working just fine. is there any compatibility issue with WebApi in SQL Server 2008??

Comment: I would create a simple console app that performs an ADO.NET call to SQL Server doing the same "simple select". you should be ruling everything out before jumping to that conclusion...

Comment: @Martin please take a look at the difference:

Production Server: http://bit.ly/W2GtjQ
Ordinary VPS: http://bit.ly/Zscu1X

for example the authentication for a special type of employee (SP) takes 16457 ms in the production server whereas in the vps, it takes only 55ms.

production server uses SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and the vps uses sql 2008 express